# calculate the values from within two queries

Tags: sql-server

is there a way in SQL server that can calculate the results from two seperate query? ex:

```
Select sum(product) as Items1
From product1

Items1
8,958

Select sum(product) as Items2
From product2

Items2
40,465
```

Now, I would like to get the the % of Items1 divided by Items2 (8,958/40,465) which gives me 22%. I would like to ask if this can be done using query in SQL server. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use variables

```
DECLARE @Sum1 FLOAT,
        @Sum2 FLOAT

Select @Sum1 = sum(product) as Items1 
From product1 

Select @Sum2 = sum(product) as Items2 
From product2 

SELECT  @Sum1 / @Sum2
```

Another would be something like

```
SELECT  Items1 / Items2
FROM    (
            Select sum(product) as Items1 From product1 
        ) a,
        (
            Select sum(product) as Items2 From product2
        ) b
```

Comment: Thank you all! the query SELECT  Items1 / Items2 
FROM    ( 
            Select sum(product) as Items1 From product1  
        ) a, 
        ( 
            Select sum(product) as Items2 From product2 
        ) b 
runs but return a 0 value. Anything reason why?

Comment: Are the values you are summing INTs?

Comment: Astander, you are correct. They are INTs. How do I convert to float? Should I declare the float variables?

Comment: Only need to do 1. So, something like *SELECT Items1 / CAST(Items2 AS FLOAT)* ,also be ware that you need to check for division by zero.

Comment: Astander, I truly appreciate your educated experience. Thanks you and everyone else for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select items1 / items2
  from (select sum(product) as items1 from product1)
      ,(select sum(product) as items2 from product2)
```

or

```
select (select sum(product) as items1 from product1) / 
       (select sum(product) as items2 from product2)
```